# Optional argument in `File.read` with Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, file, ruby-1.9.2

According to the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/IO.html#method-c-read), I believe the example below with Ruby 1.9.2 should work in the same way as Ruby 1.9.3, but it doesn't. Given a file `test` with the contents `hello`:

Ruby 1.9.3p484:

```
File.read "test", 4, :mode => 'rb'
# => "HELL"
```

Ruby 1.9.2p320

```
File.read "test", 4, :mode => 'rb'
# => TypeError: can't convert Hash into Integer
```

It seems like Ruby 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 differ in their way of handling optional args to `File.read`. Why? I cannot figure out where it's stated that this change was made.

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce this (Ruby 1.9.3p286, i386-cygwin / Ruby 1.9.3p125, i386-mingw32)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt it have to be reproduced on 1.9.2, I believe

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ You're right, of course. Apparently, I was somewhat confused :-)

Comment: I don't have 1.9.2 installed anywhere to confirm, but I suspect you'll see the problem go away if you use parenthesis around your parameters. While parenthesis are optional, they're very important, especially when dealing with multiple params, and even more so with blocks. I recommend always using them to remove any ambiguity, but YMMV.

Comment: @theTinMan It's not a syntax or ambiguity issue. I can reproduce this too when removing any ambiguity with parenthesis. Merely, it seems to be an issue of properly parsing the options hash from the arguments list.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Ruby 1.9.2 also expects the offset if you specify the length (in related news, I can also reproduce this on 1.9.2p320 but not on 1.9.3p484). It is not clear to me from the documentation and the C code why this would be required on 1.9.2 but it shouldn't be too big a problem here.

You can just use pass the offset as `nil` and it will work fine on 1.9.3 and 1.9.2.

```
File.read "test", 4, nil, :mode => 'rb'
```

Comment: The method signature `read(name, [length [, offset]], open_args)` has no default values, so, in order to pass in the `open_args`, the previous values have to precede them. `0` would probably be acceptable for the offset since the OP wants to read from the start of the file.

Comment: Passing in `nil` or 0 would probably work, but I was more interested in *why* this is a problem in the first place, and *why* it apparently isn't in 1.9.3. Is it a bug in 1.9.2?

Answer (score 0):

Complementing Holger Just's answer.

The source code actually seems to be different.

Ruby 1.9.2

```
               static VALUE
rb_io_s_read(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE io)
{
    VALUE offset;
    struct foreach_arg arg;

    rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "13", NULL, NULL, &offset, NULL);
    open_key_args(argc, argv, &arg);
    if (NIL_P(arg.io)) return Qnil;
    if (!NIL_P(offset)) {
        struct seek_arg sarg;
        int state = 0;
        sarg.io = arg.io;
        sarg.offset = offset;
        sarg.mode = SEEK_SET;
        rb_protect(seek_before_access, (VALUE)&sarg, &state);
        if (state) {
            rb_io_close(arg.io);
            rb_jump_tag(state);
        }
        if (arg.argc == 2) arg.argc = 1;
    }
    return rb_ensure(io_s_read, (VALUE)&arg, rb_io_close, arg.io);
}
```

Ruby 1.9.3

```
               static VALUE
rb_io_s_read(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE io)
{
    VALUE opt, offset;
    struct foreach_arg arg;

    argc = rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "13:", NULL, NULL, &offset, NULL, &opt);
    open_key_args(argc, argv, opt, &arg);
    if (NIL_P(arg.io)) return Qnil;
    if (!NIL_P(offset)) {
        struct seek_arg sarg;
        int state = 0;
        sarg.io = arg.io;
        sarg.offset = offset;
        sarg.mode = SEEK_SET;
        rb_protect(seek_before_access, (VALUE)&sarg, &state);
        if (state) {
            rb_io_close(arg.io);
            rb_jump_tag(state);
        }
        if (arg.argc == 2) arg.argc = 1;
    }
    return rb_ensure(io_s_read, (VALUE)&arg, rb_io_close, arg.io);
}
```

And the diff is:

[image: diff]

So they are actually different.